# SFTP can't access but SSH working fine when I changed ssh port?

Tags: networking, ssh, iptables, remote-access, sftp

I'm using `iptables` firewall for `httpd` with `whitelist` from `CloudFlare`.

This is my rule of `iptables` and I had change SSH port to `2204`

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  199.27.128.0/21      anywhere            multiport dports http,https 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  198.41.128.0/17      anywhere            multiport dports http,https 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  197.234.240.0/22     anywhere            multiport dports http,https 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  190.93.240.0/20      anywhere            multiport dports http,https 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  188.114.96.0/20      anywhere            multiport dports http,https 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  173.245.48.0/20      anywhere            multiport dports http,https 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  172.64.0.0/13        anywhere            multiport dports http,https 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  162.158.0.0/15       anywhere            multiport dports http,https 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  141.101.64.0/18      anywhere            multiport dports http,https 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  131.0.72.0/22        anywhere            multiport dports http,https 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  108.162.192.0/18     anywhere            multiport dports http,https 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  104.16.0.0/12        anywhere            multiport dports http,https 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  103.31.4.0/22        anywhere            multiport dports http,https 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  103.22.200.0/22      anywhere            multiport dports http,https 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  103.21.244.0/22      anywhere            multiport dports http,https 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  116.2.22.0/24        anywhere            tcp dpt:b2-license
```

After that, I can access SSH normally but SFTP I can't.
Look like my new SSH port same with `b2-license` port.

This is issue I'm facing?

This is error I got from FileZilla

```
Status: Waiting to retry...
Status: Connecting to xx.xx.xx.xx:2204...
Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=4
Command:    open "root@xx.xx.xx.xx" 2204
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

And login fine with `ssh`

```
Last login: Sun Jul 31 14:07:34 2016 from my-ip
```

Update: I can connect to sftp by Tunilier but can't connect by FileZilla

I'm really thanks if have any idea in this case..

Comment: What error do you get with SFTP? Show us successful SSH connection and failing SFTP connection.

Comment: I had update in my question. Please take a look.

Comment: Well I was looking for a comparable tests, like `ssh -v` and `sftp -v`

Comment: I'm not sure I can understand your mind. What should I do now sir?

Comment: Use command line `sftp`command with `-v` argument to show what is the error there.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I think -v don't have in argument list of sftp command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it may be possible that the filezilla client you are running does not support the same encryption algorithms as your server requires.

Have you tried to update your filezilla client? Have you tried another sftp client?

Also, does the file `/usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server` exist and has +x permissions?

Finally, you may try to run sshd in non-daemon mode with debugging options (stop sshd service, then run `/usr/sbin/sshd -Dd` and try again with your sftp client).

Comment: I'm trying update to FileZilla 3.20 but have too much issue with Ubuntu.

Comment: I have just remembered something: does your login via SSH take a long time (more than 10 seconds)?

Comment: Yes. More than 10 seconds.

Comment: Just as I thought. Filezilla does not allow you to increase the timeout for the login prompt, so "slow" sshd servers will mostly fail to connect. You may try to edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and add a `UseDNS=no` to make it respond earlier, but if either you do not want that config line or does not help reduce the login time, you won't be able to use filezilla for sftp

Comment: Okay I will try and I will let you know when I have any updates.

Comment: I have updated to newest version: 3.20 but same error.

Comment: How about the UseDNS=no in your server's sshd_config?

Comment: Working perfect but why this is issue?

Comment: And if I setting it. Have any security problems?

Comment: Filezilla has a fixed timeout, thus you need to speed your server response. UseDNS=yes (default) in sshd lets the sshd server log the reverse dns lookup of the ip of the client that tries to connect (so instead of 8.8.8.8 in the logs it would say something like dns.google.com). Nevertheles, reverse dns lookups are pretty slow and they tend to fail (a timed out request), so disabling them in sshd_config speeds the login.NOTE: It disables rules that relies on domain or host names (filters in sshd_config like Host or from) so if you nned them you'll need to convert them to IP

Comment: No security concerns beyond what I already explained: if you use hostnames or domain names inside sshd_config they won't work as they cannot longer be converted. But changing them into IP inside the sshd_config should work

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to connect to your sftp server from an IP address that is not allowed. You are only allowing addressed in the network `116.2.22.0/24`

> ACCEPT     tcp  --  116.2.22.0/24        anywhere            tcp dpt:b2-license

Have you actually tried connecting to ssh on port 2204

```
ssh -p 2204 user@remote.tld
```

I suspect you'll get the same timeout.

Comment: My IP is 116.2.22.49 and I connect to SSH by command line normally, don't have any error. But with FileZilla I can't connect?

Comment: Have you enabled sftp on your server ?

Comment: Yes,  I;m sure....

Comment: What is the exact command you use to log in with ssh ?

Comment: ssh -p 2204 root@ip-my-server

Comment: Look like you understand wrong my issue. I can't access sftp by FileZilla, but access SSH normally, fine.

Comment: No, I understand the issue, I was trying to diagnose it. Under normal circumstances if ssh works then sftp will work providing the remote server has sftp configured.

Comment: Yes sir, more clue is: I can access SFTP by Tunnelier but with FileZilla not work.

Answer (score 0):

When you use sftp, the sshd server process starts a helper application (you should see a reference to this in sshd_config). I'm wondering if there is some advanced security component — such as SELinux — that does not allow it to work on that port.

What OS distribution/version are you using?

If using a RHEL-based distribution, what does `sestatus` report?

Comment: Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-042stab113.11 #1 SMP Fri Dec 18 17:32:04 MSK 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: SELinux status:                 disabled

Comment: Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to protocol versioning.

Are you inning the most recent version of FileZilla?

This post suggests that an update may be useful: https://support.mayfirst.org/ticket/11270

Also you might try WinSCP, which I know to work well (assuming you're using Windows of course)

Comment: I have updated to newest version: 3.20 but same error.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem until I saw ssh uses a -p argument for port and sftp uses -P (upper case).  Both error mysteriously when the case is wrong on the option.  Since it is working for you with one client, it must be a configuration issue like this.